# Not able to fetch user details when i am click on customer name which is display in react table

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in Reactjs, now I'm going to stuck on code where i have to fetch the customers details from react table where i show the customer names, Problem is when i'm click on customer name it is showing the particular customer id in url but when i click on name it is not showing customer details.

The below code is used where i have to show user details:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { match: id } = this.props;

    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var tabparams = {
      TableName: 'TestProjectList',
      FilterExpression: 'id = :UserId',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':UserId': id
      }
    };
}
```

The below code i link the id parameter in table for customer name

```
          <Table>
           <Table.Body>
            {projectList.map((item, index) => 
            // {projectList.map(project => 
            <Table.Row key={item.id} className="btnHover">
              <Table.Cell>{item.id}</Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell >
                <Link to={`./customer-details/${item.id}`}>{item.customer_name}</Link>
              </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>)}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
```

Once i click on customer name i have to show details of customer like,
Customer name, project, category

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
 getDetails = (i)=>{
    console.log(projectList[i])
   }

   render(){
      return(
     <Table>
           <Table.Body>
            {projectList.map((item, index) => 
            // {projectList.map(project => 
            <Table.Row key={item.id} className="btnHover">
              <Table.Cell>{item.id}</Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell >
                <button onClick={(e)=>this.getDetails(index)}>{item.customer_name}</button>
              </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>)}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
      )
  }
```

section section

```
    render(){
     if(this.state.selectedCUstomer){
        return(
           <CustomerComponent {...this.state.data}/>
         )
     }else{
        return(
          <Table />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have to show details on new page. This is working for me. But requirement is to show particular customer details on another page.

Comment: first of all, create another component. after that you when some click in your table then keeps it in a state something like selected user. In your render method conditionally render that component with data

Comment: I have added component and through match id going to fetch the details.

Comment: you are almost there not conditionally render your component check my answer in second section

Answer (score 1):

try and tell me if it work or nott 
dont deoget

```
import  Link  from "react-router-dom";

<Link to={`/customer-details/${item.id}`}>{item.customer_name}</Link>
```

Comment: are create router customer-details/:id

Comment: Yes it is created, Once i click on customer name the url is look like http://localhost:3000/customer-details/2

Comment: i created one component and there i'm going to show the customer details.